# Show Div by clicking on button, hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I want the content of the div container with the ID = '1' to be displayed when I click on the "Europe" button. 
When clicking on the button "USA" the content of the DIV with id 2 should be displayed.

I have the following problems with my code:
I can't manage to select that no DIV or only a specific one is displayed when the page is loaded.
After the first click on the button the function does not work anymore.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

```js
function showOne(id) {
    $('.hide').not('#' + id).hide();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="showOne('1')">Europe</button>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="showOne('2')">USA</button>
<div class='hide' id='2'>About USA</div>
<div class='hide' id='1'>About Europe</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to show the current div first on button click like:

```js
function showOne(id) {
    $('#' + id).show();
    $('.hide').not('#' + id).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="showOne('1')">Europe</button>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="showOne('2')">USA</button>
<div class='hide' id='2'>About USA</div>
<div class='hide' id='1'>About Europe</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `.show()` method to show all of that elements before hiding:

```js
function showOne(id) {
    $('.hide').show().not('#' + id).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="showOne('1')">Europe</button>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="showOne('2')">USA</button>
<div class='hide' id='2'>About USA</div>
<div class='hide' id='1'>About Europe</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is honestly a really simple problem, I'm sure that there's already an answer to such problems, in any case, you could do something like this:

### Edit

Might I add that this solution includes only web native technologies, no jQuery has been included, I'm not sure if this is a pro or a con in your eyes. In any case, if you'd like to learn more about the native JavaScript I've used, perhaps [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) would be a good starting point.

```js
function showOne(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".hide").forEach(function (el) {
    el.style = "display: block;";
  });
  
  document.querySelector(".hide[id='" + id + "']").style = "display: none;";
};
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="showOne('1')">Europe</button>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="showOne('2')">USA</button>
<div class='hide' id='1'>About USA</div>
<div class='hide' id='2'>About Europe</div>
```